# Reorder rows in data.table in a specific order

Tags: r, sorting, data.table

I have a `data.table` `dumdt`:

```
set.seed(123)
dumdt <- data.table(v1=sample(1:10, 5), v2=1:5)
```

whose rows I'd like to reorder in this specific indices order (so first the third observation, then the fifth, then second, etc.):

```
to_ord <- c(3, 5, 2, 1, 4)
```

So I'd like `dumdt` to be the result of `dumdt[to_ord]` but I also would like to do it by reference and avoid doing `dumdt <- dumdt[to_ord]`.

I know I can reorder rows by reference with `setorder` (or `setorderv`) but only according to one or several variables, in ascending or descending order, not in a customised order.
However, if I wanted to reorder the columns, not the rows, in a customised order, I could use `setcolorder`.

So here comes my question : is there a function that would work like `setcolorder` but with the rows (or a way to use `setorder` to do the same) ?

My desired output would be something like

```
setroworder(x=dumdt, neworder=to_ord)
dumdt
   # v1 v2
# 1:  4  3
# 2:  6  5
# 3:  8  2
# 4:  3  1
# 5:  7  4
```

Comment: Isn't `setorder(cbind(dumdt,to_ord),to_ord)` (then set to_ord to NULL) fast enough?

Comment: @EricLecoutre Thank you for your comment, I'm not sure the use of `cbind` will be efficient but anyway, this would change the unassigned output of `cbind` and not the initial object so that wouldn't really help. (and actually I'm quite convinced the output wouldn't be the expected one...)

Comment: Yeks... Indeed. Always some difficulties with references...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This capability is not (yet) exported. After looking at the source of `setorderv` I was able to extract required call to C function which does what you need and supply it with custom order.

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
dumdt <- data.table(v1=sample(1:10, 5), v2=1:5)
print(dumdt)
#   v1 v2
#1:  3  1
#2:  8  2
#3:  4  3
#4:  7  4
#5:  6  5
setroworder <- function(x, neworder) {
    .Call(data.table:::Creorder, x, as.integer(neworder), PACKAGE = "data.table")
    invisible(x)
}
to_ord <- c(3, 5, 2, 1, 4)
setroworder(x=dumdt, neworder=to_ord)
print(dumdt)
#   v1 v2
#1:  4  3
#2:  6  5
#3:  8  2
#4:  3  1
#5:  7  4
```

Yet the solution proposed by Frank looks a little bit nicer.

Comment: This just looks like magic to me ;-) Thank you very much, you just created the function I would have wanted to exist. Now I feel like a spoilt girl ;-)

Comment: In general I think the Frank's answer is a little more correct, in terms that it rely only on exported functions from data.table, unlike mine where `:::` is used to access not exported function.

Comment: you think `Creorder` could get modified in a way your function will not work anymore ? Probably both answers have their advantages/pitfalls. And I agree that Frank's is more "suitable" for a day-to-day use but yours is less "ordinary" in the "cool way" Frank is mentioning :-) (and obviously I'm not implying anything "bad" for Frank's answer, which is also really great)

Comment: @Frank good point with ordering twice. BTW. wrapper on Frank's solution if anyone prefer: `setroworder <- function(x, neworder) setorderv(x[, eval(call(":=", as.name(".r"), call("order", neworder)))], ".r")[, ".r" := NULL]`

Answer (score 25):

If I understand correctly, you can just add a col and then order by it:

```
setorder(dumdt[, .r := order(to_ord)], .r)[, .r := NULL]

   v1 v2
1:  4  3
2:  6  5
3:  8  2
4:  3  1
5:  7  4
```

Comment: nice way of "doubling" the order of `to_ord`, I didn't figure out how to use order on it, didn't thinjk `order(order(to_ord))==to_ord` :-)

Comment: OK, but what if we add a row to `dumdt` or delete a row from `dumdt`? Then we need to modify `to_ord` somehow...

Comment: @JS1204 Adding and removing rows by reference isn't possible, though you could make a new table by subsetting or using rbind. If you want to drop something, I guess setting its to_ord value to NA and then filtering out NAs might work; but I'm not sure what it means to add a row here. You could try asking a new question (since I guess my comment won't be sufficient as I don't fully understand the problem you're describing)

Comment: Thanks. I'm thinking of a situation where `dumdt` is slightly different from that in the original post. The original post is a special case where `v2` and `to_ord` contain exactly the same numbers of elements, and all the elements of `v2` are unique.