# setorder danish letters or custom ordering of letters in a data table

Tags: r, data.table

I want to order my data table alphabetically, and since I am from Denmark, I would like to order Æ, Ø and Å also. They are ordered correctly like this:

```
dk <- c(LETTERS, "Æ", "Ø", "Å")
dk
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q" "R" 
"S" "T" "U" "V" "W" "X" "Y" "Z" "Æ" "Ø" "Å"
```

setorder in library(data.table) would be nice for this, but if I make a data table that has danish letters that needs to be sorted, setorder sets the wrong order:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(v1=c("Brød", "Ål", "Øl", "Snegl", "Æble"), v2=1:5)
setorder(DT)

DT
v1 v2
1:  Brød  1
2: Snegl  4
3:    Ål  2
4:  Æble  5
5:    Øl  3
```

Is there a way to customize setorder? I looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37878620/reorder-rows-in-data-table-in-a-specific-order) question, but that only works if you have a set amount of rows?

Using base::sort will get me this order, don't know if it has to do with my computer settings, but it is curious that the order is different (and still wrong):

```
sort(DT$v1)
[1] "Æble"  "Ål"    "Brød"  "Øl"    "Snegl"
```

Suggestions from other packages are also very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution which uses match, with inspiration from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17031039/how-to-sort-a-character-vector-according-to-a-specific-order). It is not perfect, so would like still like another method, so i dont have to define the order myself. What if there are both Øl and Øllebrød, which one comes first then?

```
DT[order(match(substr(DT$v1, 1,1), dk))]

      v1 v2
1:  Brød  1
2: Snegl  4
3:  Æble  5
4:    Øl  3
5:    Ål  2
```

EDIT: This method is slightly better, but I feel that I am on a path that leads to just more trouble...

```
DT <- data.table(v1=c("Brød", "Ål", "Øl", "Øllebrød", "Brav", "Brøl", "Snegl", "Æble"), v2=1:8)

DK <- c(LETTERS, "Æ", "Ø", "Å")
dk <- c(letters, "æ", "ø", "å")
Dk <- c("", rbind(DK, dk)) 

nr <- max(nchar(DT$v1))
for(i in nr:1){
DT <- DT[order(match(substr(DT$v1, i,i), Dk))]
}

> DT
         v1 v2
1:     Brav  5
2:     Brød  1
3:     Brøl  6
4:    Snegl  7
5:     Æble  8
6:       Øl  3
7: Øllebrød  4
8:       Ål  2
```