# Use expression in data.table::setorder()

Tags: r, data.table

When ordering rows of a `data.frame` in base R with `order()` we can use expressions inside the ellipsis, as shown in the example below where we bring the row `"Hornet Sportabout"` to the top:

```r
# setup
cars_short <- head(mtcars, 8)[,1:5]

mycars <- data.frame(model = rownames(cars_short),
                     data.frame(cars_short, row.names=NULL))

# bring row to the top
mycars[order(mycars$model!="Hornet Sportabout"),]
#>               model  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat
#> 5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15
#> 1         Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90
#> 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90
#> 3        Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85
#> 4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08
#> 6           Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76
#> 7        Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21
#> 8         Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69
```

We can use `order()` on a `data.table`, and it will yield the same result. However, `data.table::setorder()` seems not be able to accept expressions in the ellipsis argument. Somehow data.table interprets the expression as several column names.

```
library(data.table)
mycarsDT <- as.data.table(mycars)

# working
mycarsDT[order(model!="Hornet Sportabout"),]
#>                model  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat
#> 1: Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15
#> 2:         Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90
#> 3:     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90
#> 4:        Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85
#> 5:    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08
#> 6:           Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76
#> 7:        Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21
#> 8:         Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69

# not working
setorder(mycarsDT, model!="Hornet Sportabout")
#> Error in setorderv(x, cols, order, na.last): some columns are not in the data.table: !=,Hornet Sportabout
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Is this in general not possible? Is there a workaround using the more efficient `setorder()` instead of `order()`? Is this a bug?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: From checking the help file, it doesn't look like `setorder` accepts expressions. You'd have to revert to using `order` inside the data.table `[]`

Comment: A workaround would be to add the order variable and then drop it again `setorder(mycarsDT[, ord := model != "Hornet Sportabout"], ord)[, ord := NULL]` - though I imagine that isn't any more efficient than just `order`ing.

Comment: The documentation in my version says that column names should not be quoted, but it doesn’t say that only unquoted column names are accepted in the ellipsis. Coming from dplyr this is pretty unexpected.

Comment: I understand your frustration, and that dplyr tends to accept expressions (which may resolve to just the symbol/column-contents) and data.table seems to only accept symbols of columns, that would certainly be a nice thing to address in data.table ... what's your motivation for needing to use `setorder` here? From `?setorder`, it does say *"Note that queries like 'x[order(.)]' are optimised internally to use 'data.table''s fast order"*, suggesting that while not the encouraged method, `DT[order(..),]` can still be optimized. (In other words, isn't it still in-place efficient?)

Comment: Yes I read that, but `setorder()` should still be more efficient, since it modifies the DT in place. When using data.table I usually need any speed I can get, so I usually stick to  the set* functions.

Comment: Yeah, I think you're right. I suggest you write a feature-request, though [#4012](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4012) (and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37878620/3358272) are a little related for in-place reordering (albeit by providing the order of rows explicitly).